# Populate a ListView from a Json file in C#

Tags: c#, json, listview, xamarin

I am working with Xamarin and C# to create some basic Android application.
I am in the learning process.

What I am trying to do is to populate a ListView with some data extract from a JSON file. 
I have made two methods, one async task to call the server and one for parsing and extract the data (http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json).

My problem now is that I don't have any idea how to feed the listview with this data.

Thank you for your time.

```
namespace App4 
{
[Activity(Label = "App4", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    //Declare a Cancellation Token Source 
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    Button startbutton;
    Button stopbutton;
    TextView textView0;
    ListView listView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        startbutton = FindViewById<Button>
            (Resource.Id.startbutton);
        stopbutton = FindViewById<Button>
            (Resource.Id.stopbutton);
        textView0 = FindViewById<TextView>
            (Resource.Id.textView0);
        listView = FindViewById<ListView>
            (Resource.Id.listView);


        //BASIC ASYNC START TASK
        // click the startbutton to start the process
        startbutton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {                
            // Instantiate the CancellationTokenSource
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                // **** GET ****
               await Task.Run(() => LoadDataAsync(cts.Token));

            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                textView0.Text = " Download deleted ";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                textView0.Text = "Generic Error";
            }

            // ***Set the CancellationTokenSource to null when the download is complete.
            cts = null;
        };

        //STOP BUTTON 
        stopbutton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        };
    }

    //THIS METHOD LOAD JSON DATA FROM AN URL AND RETURN A STRING

    public static async Task<string> LoadDataAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // Call the server and take the file
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024; //read up to 1MB of data

        await Task.Delay(250);//Delay the task for deleting purpose

        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json"), ct);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return result;

    }

    //THIS METHOD GET THE JSON DATA FROM THE STRING 

    private static void GetData(string result)
    {

        // Parse the Json file.
        JArray file = JArray.Parse(result);

        foreach (var item in file.Children<JObject>())
        {               
            string name = (string)item.SelectToken("nm");
            string city = (string)item.SelectToken("cty");
            string house = (string)item.SelectToken("hse");
            string years = (string)item.SelectToken("yrs");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you need to create a domain object that has properties for each data element (name, city, etc) and then create a List of those objects in your GetData method.  They use a ListAdapater to feed that data to your ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few things and will suggest you change a few others so that it can be easier.

First create an entity/class with the data you will be receiving from the API. Call it as you wish but for this example I will call it **EnglishMonarch**

```
public class EnglishMonarch
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public string City {get; set;}

    public string House {get; set;}

    public string Years {get; set;}
}
```

As you see I added a public property with each field you will be receiving.

I suggest you to use this library [Json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) which will allow you to parse the json data into your entity with only a few lines of code. You can install the nuget package right from XS or VS.

You will need to include some changes to the class we just created. You will add some annotations so json.net knows how to map each json fields with your class properties.

```
public class EnglishMonarch
{
    [JsonProperty("nm")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cty")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hse")]
    public string House { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("yrs")]
    public string Years { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can get the response and parse it using json.net like this:

```
public List<EnglishMonarch> GetData (string jsonData)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (jsonData))
        return new List<EnglishMonarch> ();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EnglishMonarch>> (jsonData);
}
```

Note: Why a list of `EnglishMonarch`? because you are receiving from the API more than one item this is the list you will use to populate your `ListView`.

Now let's put that data into your ListView. In Android for this you need to create an [Adapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/) which is the one that tells the `ListView` how and what data to display.

Your adapter will look like this:

```
public class EnglishMonarchAdapter : BaseAdapter<EnglishMonarch>
{
    public List<EnglishMonarch> Items { get; set;}

    private readonly Context context;

    public EnglishMonarchAdapter (Context context, List<EnglishMonarch> items)
    {
        this.context = context;

        Items = items ?? new List<EnglishMonarch> ();
    }

    public override EnglishMonarch this [int position]
    {
        get { return Items [position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return Items.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView ?? LayoutInflater.FromContext (context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.englishmonarch_item_layout, parent, false);

        var item = Items [position];

        var tvName = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvName);
        var tvHouse = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvHouse);
        var tvYear = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvYears);
        var tvCity = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvCity);

        tvName.Text = item.Name;
        tvHouse.Text = item.House;
        tvYear.Text = item.Years;
        tvCity.Text = item.City;

        return view;
    }
}
```

The `GetView` method is the one responsible of creating the ListView Item view (the Cell) and mapping the data to the fields in the view.

For this Adapter to work you will need to create a Layout (XML) which will be the one used as a ItemView/Cell of your ListView. The one I created is very simple and I named it **englishmonarch_item_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCity" 
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHouse" 
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvYears" 
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you just have to glue some pieces in your `startButton` click event

```
    startbutton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {                
        // Instantiate the CancellationTokenSource
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            // **** GET ****
           var jsonData = await LoadDataAsync(cts.Token);

           // ** Parse data into your entity ****
           var items = GetData(jsonData);

           // **** Create your adapter passing the data *****
           listview.Adapter = new EnglishMonarchAdapter(this, items);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            textView0.Text = " Download deleted ";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            textView0.Text = "Generic Error";
        }

        // ***Set the CancellationTokenSource to null when the download is complete.
        cts = null;
    };
```

That's all. That should work!

Note: You can skip a few parts like the use of Json.net and parse your data manually, just did mention it so you know there're other options.

Comment: This is a complete and extraordinary answer. 
Thank you very much for your time!